# Next.JS: Make server side fetch depend on client side select input

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

First up, I'm new to Next and I'm using Next 13.1 with the app directory.

I need a select input in my application that is used to switch between the different years of data I'm looking at.
The data of the entire application (content, side navigation bar, top navigation bar) depends on the selected year, because I need to fetch data from different paths depending on which year is selected.

Currently I am fetching all the data server side, and I am setting a searchParam when the select input value changes. Because the search params can only be accessed in Page components on the server side, I'm converting the search param to a request header using middleware, so every server-side component can access it. This leads to a complete reload of the page every time a link is clicked.

My question is: How do I implement the functionality described above? I am obviously doing something wrong, but I'm new to client / server components and therefore don't know the best design practices.

```
// The select input:
<StyledTextField select defaultValue={currentYear ?? years.find(year => year.is_active)?.id}>
    {years.map(year=> (
        <MenuItem value={year.id} key={year.id} className={"yearSelectItem"}>
            <Link href={{pathname: pathname, query: {year: year.id}}}>
                {year.name} {year.is_active && "(aktiv)"}
            </Link>
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</StyledTextField>
```

```
// The middleware:
const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
requestHeaders.set("x-year", request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("year") ?? "")
const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
        headers: requestHeaders
    }
})

return response;
```

```
// This is how I access the header in server-side components:
headers().get("x-year")
```

Comment: There is some technics with URLSearchParams.
in the client side you will put into search params you input value, something like

const handleChnage = (query) => {
    let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (query) {
      params.set("search", query);
    } else {
      params.delete("search");
    }
    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
  };

so in your Url you will see `yoururl/?search=[your input value]`
and then you take it on your server side page from searchParams

let search = searchParams?.search and put as parameter to fetch

Comment: you can ispire from this one : https://twitter.com/ryantotweets/status/1622632897051082752

Comment: This is a great example, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change the issue that searchParams can only be accessed inside of Page components